# Make MVC App connect to different Database based on the Sub domain the user entered

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have Software in which a Company will register itself first, at that time a database especially for the company will be created. After that they will add Information about their Employees and can Create there Users (Admin, Manager, etc) and do different Operations within that database. 
Now I have an MVC web app for this and Two Clients who would like to use this software but with information storing in different Databases. 
The Point is I have domain lets say www.mangementInfo.com.

Now a User one wants to access his Application using Sub Domain like this
User1.mangementInfo.com

And Similarly User2 using
User2.mangementInfo.com
How can I publish my app once but connect different database based on the sub Domain entered.

I know I will be getting plenty of down votes for this question but I really want to know can we publish mvc app one and have it connected to different databases depending on the sub domain the system is accessed from. Please share your views about how can I make this system work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have multiple connection strings configured and pick the one you want based on the domain of the request. In ASP.NET, check the HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host property and make a decision.